# Is there a way to get realtime sales data for an App Store app?

Tags: app-store-connect

Is there a way to get realtime sales data for an App Store app?

It seems App Store Connect API lets you download sales zipped files - is that realtime? Is there a way to query instead of grabbing the entire dump?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot access truly real-time sales data for an App Store app, even through the App Store Connect API. Here's what you need to know:

App Store Connect Sales & Trends Reports:

Data Refresh: While it offers the most detailed picture, data in Sales & Trends reports updates approximately every 2 hours for the last 24 hours. So, it's not truly real-time.
Downloadable vs. Query:You can't directly query the data. Instead, you download zipped reports containing historical sales data within the chosen timeframe. These reports offer various filters for insights.

App Store Connect API:

Similar to Reports: The API also fetches data in 2-hour increments for the last 24 hours. It doesn't provide real-time sales information.
Downloading Zips: Similar to reports, you download zipped files containing sales data with the API.
No Live Stream: No API endpoint offers a live feed of sales data as transactions occur.

Alternative Solutions:

Hourly Data: App Store Connect does offer hourly sales data for the last 24 hours, but with a 2-hour delay. It's not strictly real-time but provides more granular insights compared to daily reports.
External Tools: Some third-party services like Sensor Tower and AppAnnie claim to offer real-time app sales estimates. However, they rely on their own methodologies and estimations, not actual Apple data.

Overall:

While real-time App Store sales data isn't directly available, available tools provide near-real-time insights with a slight delay. Remember, these tools also have limitations and might not perfectly represent your app's actual sales in every moment.